# Solving an inequality with the "<>" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, solver, inequality

How to solve an inequality in MATLAB with the `<>` operator, 
I tried to run the following example (the solution is `x=y` or `y`):

```
syms x y;
eqn1 = x^2==y^2;
eqn2 = 3*x<>3*y;
eqn = [eqn1 eqn2];
solve(eqn)
```

but I get an error. The help doesn't give [an answer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#bue6nzl-10).
If there's not a built-in solution, how can I specify the values to except for the `solve` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `not equal` operator `<>` is defined in Matlab as [`~= (docs)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ne.html), so you could change your code to:

```
syms x y;
eqn1 = x^2 == y^2;
eqn2 = 3*x ~= 3*y;
eqn = [eqn1 eqn2];
solve(eqn)
```

Comment: @rm6 you bet. Glad I could help.